# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy while creating hdfs directories

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

`FileSystem.getConfig(config)` throws `org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy exception` while trying to create HDFS directories.

```
config.addResource(new Path(String.format("%s/core-site.xml",TestProperties.HDFS_CONF_DIR)));
config.addResource(new Path(String.format("%s/hdfs-site.xml",TestProperties.HDFS_CONF_DIR)));
config.set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
config.set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());
FileSystem dfs = FileSystem.get(config);
```

Attached the complete stack trace :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(Ljava/lang/Class;JLjava/net/InetSocketAddress;Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljavax/net/SocketFactory;ILorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/RetryPolicy;Z)Lorg/apache/hadoop/ipc/VersionedProtocol;
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:135)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:280)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.(DFSClient.java:245)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2761)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2795)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2777)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:386)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:179)  at
>   org.apache.atlas.regression.util.HDFSUtil.createDirectory(HDFSUtil.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.atlas.regression.tests.FalconIntegrationTest.setUp(FalconIntegrationTest.java:43)

Hadoop version in the cluster is 2.7.3 and in pom.xml 2.7.3. What could be the issue?

Comment: Adding the hadoop-client dependency resolved the issue .

Comment: Which client version. I have hadoop-client jar but still getting this issue